# How to share by url link a Saiku query

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, saiku

could someone tell me how to share a query saiku by url? When I try it on another computer using "open in new window" url sends me to the initial screen of pentaho server. I tried using:

> http://localhost:8080/pentaho/api/repos/path:mysaikuquery.saiku/run

but it disables the edit functions, and i need them.

Thank you very much in advance!!
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a very active community around pentaho and their plugins like saiku. I have posted it in saiku community forums as well. But to tell that saiku have nothing to be related with pentaho...really I dont understand your comment, when the people who works with Saiku is used to use Pentaho suite too.

I found a temporal solution accidentally, so I'll share it: in Pentaho console, right mouse click on the tab with the saiku project opened (after have ejecuted it on browse file of course), and on the new menu choose the option "Create a deep link"...copy and paste it where you need it. It works with users and roles, so you will need such credentials to be able to view and modify the query to the cube. So it's perfect to share projects with clients or non admin users.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a saiku issue, not pentaho's.

Why don't you ask to the [author](https://meteorite.bi/products/sai) or the [community](https://community.meteorite.bi/). Unlike Pentaho they do not charge for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with edit instead of run?
I'm not sure it will work or not, I have worked long back ago